# Free Money Payroll from Ghost Accounts

Tags: bank-account, scams, fraud, accounts, payroll

My friend said he knows this guy who will deposit money into my Chase bank account. The only requirements being that I have had the account for over 4 months and my balance is not negative. 
His name is Antonio and he states he can set me up with a payroll; deposit $1,500 into my account once a month for the next 3 months.
When I asked where this money is coming from he stated from Ghost Accounts.

What is this?! It sounds illegal/fraud. Anyone heard of something like this?

Comment: You mention getting set up with payroll. Is this person going to employ you? Will you be doing work in exchange for this money?

Comment: No. He will be depositing money into my account for free. All he needs is my account information.

Comment: More probably than illegal, a scam (that still is illegal, of course). If he is going to deposit money, why does he need the balance not to be negative? Banks do not reject incoming transfers because the account is in negative numbers. And if for some odd reason it is not a scam, it will be still illegal (there is no free money).

Comment: This has to be a duplicate of some scam question, just can't find which one...

Comment: @yoozer8 - We should be able to find a decent "stranger trying to give me money" and call it quits. There are tiny differences, ways to send the money/ receive the money, different things the recipient has to do, but in the end, we don't need 100 variations of the same scam.

Answer (score 6):

If a stranger is offering to give you a bunch of money for doing nothing, it's probably a scam. You haven't given enough info to tell how it works, but I'd guess it's a variation of something like this:

- they "deposit" $2000 into your account
- they say "oops we messed up and sent too much. please send back the additional $500"
- you do it, and then the initial "deposit" gets cancelled or fails to clear
- you're now out $500

Also, I've never heard of a "ghost account".

Comment: Is there an additional risk that OP would now have a ding on their credit report or chexsystems score? I cannot recall the impact of having returned or bounced checks deposited